# PowerMTA Config Override for Return-Path for Virtual MTA

Tags: email, spf, mail-server

Our setup uses OEM Pro to drop the emails into a PowerMTA pickup directory. OEM Pro only allows us to specify one global catch all domain. This global catch all domain is being used as the return-path and the return-path is what has to be verified by the SPF record lookup. So this is not an ideal situation since we would like each client to have their own SPF records, and have their domain in the return-path.

We have deduced that our best approach would be to configure PowerMTA to override the return-path address, is it possible to configure this the PMTA config for a Virtual MTA?

Answer (score 1):

I received the following reply from PowerMTA Support on the similar issue:

> No message content is set by PowerMTA.  We cannot set any headers. 
>   This is done by your feeding application.  Other MTA servers may offer
>   this functionality, but PowerMTA does not.

So, I changed my app  to use their .Net API, and it's possible to set MAIL FROM there.