# Email sending in GO, unable to set Return-Path header

Tags: go

I am trying to send a simple email from GO using the built-in functionality of smtp package.

My simple code looks like:

```
func sendEmail(to string, body []byte) error {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth(
        "",
        config.SmtpUsername,
        config.SmtpPassword,
        config.SmtpHostname,
    )

    return smtp.SendMail(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", config.SmtpHostname, config.SmtpPort),
        auth,
        config.SmtpUsername,
        []string{to},
        body,
    ) 
}
```

And it works, the thing is that it always sets the Return-Path header to value of the config.SmtpUsername even if i send a message that contains custom Return-Path header, basically after the message is sent, seems that somehow the Return-Path from the message is replaced with the smtp username.

Any thoughts on how i could avoid this and make GO use whatever Return-Path i give?

L.E 1: If any help, a code snippet is available at: http://play.golang.org/p/ATDCgJGKZ3
L.E 2: I can achieve the desired behavior from php with swiftmailer, thus i don't think the delivery server is changing the headers in any way.

More code:

PHP with swiftmailer, it sets proper return path:

```
Yii::import('common.vendors.SwiftMailer.lib.classes.Swift', true);
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Swift', 'autoload'));
Yii::import('common.vendors.SwiftMailer.lib.swift_init', true);

$hostname   = '';
$username   = '';
$password   = '';
$returnPath = '';
$subject    = 'Swiftmailer sending, test return path';
$toEmail    = '';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($hostname, 25);
$transport->setUsername($username);
$transport->setPassword($password);

$logger  = new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger());
$mailer  = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->registerPlugin($logger);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$message->setReturnPath($returnPath);
$message->setSubject($subject);
$message->setFrom($username);
$message->setTo($toEmail);
$message->setBody('Hello, this is a simple test going on here...');

$sent = $mailer->send($message);

print_r($logger->dump());
```

GO with a custom mysmtp package, where i just set `InsecureSkipVerify: true` in tls configuration to avoid certificate errors, still the return path is wrong :

```
hostname := ""
username := ""
password := ""
returnPath := ""
subject := "GO sending, test return path"
toEmail := ""
body := "Hello, this is a simple test going on here..."

auth := mysmtp.PlainAuth(
    "",
    username,
    password,
    hostname,
)

header := make(map[string]string)
header["Return-Path"] = returnPath
header["From"] = username
header["To"] = toEmail
header["Subject"] = subject

message := ""
for k, v := range header {
    message += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
}
message += "\r\n" + string([]byte(body))

err := mysmtp.SendMail(
    fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", hostname, 25),
    auth,
    username,
    []string{toEmail},
    []byte(message),
)

log.Fatal(err)
```

I literally have no clue what fails and why, this last test has been conducted against a postfix mta, where i just removed the `reject_sender_login_mismatch` policy from postfix configuration to allow this behavior.

Comment: Can you add your message body, and actual []byte?

Comment: @Momer - Take a look at http://play.golang.org/p/ATDCgJGKZ3  It doesn't matter what you throw in there, result is the same, return path gets overwritten

Comment: You probably won't be able to do that by code. The `Return-Path` is set (and can be reset when already present) by SMTP systems. The [RFC 5321 specifies](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#page-58) that the message-originating system SHOULD NOT specify the return-path. For example, as far as I know, if you're using Gmail and your return-path is different to your username, Gmail will reset it to your username.

Comment: @bernhardw - this particular system uses pmta to receive and send the emails further and i believe pmta doesn't really do anything to the messages since i am also using php with swiftmailer and i am able to set proper return path as i wish. I am aware of the RFC spec, but there are cases when you need to setup a different return path than the one from where you have sent the message, i.e when doing bulk mailing, since there are specific servers that do delivery and specific ones that process the incoming emails, each of them on separate boxes to handle the load.

Comment: @Twisted1919 I couldn't find any code in Go that would alter your headers in any way. And since the RFC states that it's the receivers job to set the return-path, I still suspect it's an issue with PowerMTA or any system in between or after. But it's really weird that it works with Swift Mailer. Except of the sending "software", are both stacks identically?

Comment: @bernhardw - You are right, i also looked inside go source and i could only find just one Return-Path reference in a map of common headers. Yes they are the same, i can only assume swiftmailer is doing more tricks than go's package, i'll look more into it shortly, probably a few more tests to be sure.

Comment: If it helps, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15062950/3233520) says that PowerMTA doesn't change the content (incl. headers) in any way. Maybe you could post some more infos regarding the rest of your stack.

Comment: @bernhardw yes that's the case, it won't change/add (i remember i have read this in pmta docs a while ago). I'll post here some examples from php/go when i am done at work today.

Comment: @bernhardw just updated my question with more code if that's of any help :)

Comment: @Twisted1919 If both programs are using the exact same stack (SMTP system and all other systems between and after), then it must be the sending. But I cannot find any difference responsible for that behavior, sorry.

Comment: @bernhardw yeah it's the same everything, only the programming languages differ. I am sure it's something really simple but i am just missing it. Thanks for the input so far, if you have any other idea meanwhile, feel free to share.

Comment: The go code is certainly not overwriting your Return-Path header. I suggest you sniff the SMTP data with wireshark in your 2 cases (go code and PHP code) and look for differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Return-Path is derived from the "MAIL FROM" command that the client specifies when sending the message.

Looking at the implementation details of the smtp package at http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/smtp/smtp.go it should not be too difficult to implement a SendMail function that uses an alternative address for the argument of `func (c *Client) Mail(from string) error`.

Comment: yup, you are right, this way it works just fine. i tried this as one of the first things but didn't work because postfix directive `smtpd_sender_restrictions` contained the `reject_sender_login_mismatch` rule. If i put that back in it won't work anymore, but i came to the conclusion that is the right behavior in this case.